# Sqlite3 Gem fails to install for Rails/Rvm on Mac OS Lion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, osx-lion

I'm a double-newbie: new to Mac and Rails. Picked up a new Mac (finally) on Friday, and have had trouble getting my Rails app running ever since.

Here's what I've done, including this in THIS POST:

- installed RVM
- installed Ruby 1.87, latest Rails 3.07
- installed xCode
- sudo gem install sqlite3
- updated sqlite3 just for good measure

But no change in outcome:

Here's where bundle install chokes:

Installing sqlite3 (1.3.3) with native extensions /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:551:in `build_extensions': ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError)

```
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
```

checking for sqlite3.h... yes
checking for sqlite3_libversion_number() in -lsqlite3... no
sqlite3 is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal'
or 'yum install sqlite3-devel' and check your shared library search path (the
location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

tried sudo port install sqlite3 +universal, but failed on what looks like a path error:
post: command not found

so tried again with explicit path to port: 
sudo /opt/local/bin/port install  sqlite3

which was successful, then bundle install:
same error as the first.

Is it a path issue? Compile? Frustrating.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of XCode did you install? OS X Lion appears to require [XCode 4.1](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id448457090?mt=12), which is available as a free download at the [App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id448457090?mt=12).

However, your error seems to be that you need to specify a path to the sqlite3 library. Try `gem install sqlite3 --with-sqlite3-dir=/opt/local`

BTW the latest version of the sqlite3 gem is 1.3.4; it was released recently and is more tolerant of older versions of the sqlite3 lib.